# CSS ridge border fails at the top of a div

Tags: css, border

A div formated by CSS

```
#place01
{
border-top:medium ridge #FFF;
border-bottom:medium ridge #FFF;
}
```

Bottom border is ridged, but the top - is not.
It's a plain, tiny line. Why?

Comment: Is it being overridden in another part of your style sheet?

Comment: I guess because of the white background of your page.

Comment: What is the top edge of this div merging with ?

Comment: change the background color of the container from white to something else and you'll see the white border
http://jsfiddle.net/4SNAZ/1/

Comment: And what browser are you using? I can only recall [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455054/css3-borders-style-inset-or-groove-look-very-different-from-ie9-ff4-or-safari5-o).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the background color of container of that div has the same color as the border. And taking into account the logic of the `ridge` border style that's completely normal behavior.
http://jsfiddle.net/4SNAZ/1/

Comment: Hmm, yes the problem is bckgColor, but I think it should not be the problem. AnyWay, thankyou, solved.

Answer (score 1):

Here worked perfectly: http://jsfiddle.net/WcsVH/

Comment: That's a red border. And this isn't an answer.

Comment: I changed the color just to be emphasized