# outline property CSS causing width problems in Opera 11.5?

Tags: html, css, standards, opera, outline

Okay, I've got a page with a header div that stretches 100% wide, with a 1px bottom-border and another 1px outline to fake a 'two-color' border as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3907027/1064923). This works perfectly in Firefox 4-9, Chrome, IE7/8/9, and Safari. The problem is with Opera 11.5, because of this 1px outline, opera is showing a horizontal scrollbar along the bottom of the screen, so essentially Opera is rendering the page as 100% (div width) + 2px (2x 1px outline each side), which is wrong, because apparently outline shouldn't take up any space on screen.

I've searched through stackoverflow and done multiple google searches on the issues, and I can come up with no answers or questions relating to this - there also doesn't appear to be side specific outline properties (e.g. outline-left), so I am left wondering what potential remedies there are to this?

Comment: Off the top of my head a quick fix might be overflow:hidden;

Comment: Cheers - I should've thought of this in the first place. It doesn't mess with any of the other browsers either.

Comment: Glad it worked for ya. Good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
overflow:hidden;
```

Shouldn't mess with other browsers, and will keep those pesky horizontal scrollbars away.