# How to CSS style a radius border

Tags: html, css

I'm looking to style the border like in the example picture attached.

[image]

I would like it to have a black frame, and a white effect like in the picture.

so far I have this:

```
div {
   border: 1px solid black;
   border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Comment: You'll need sone gradient effects. That can be done visually in Adobe Fireworks and then you can copy the CSS proprieties and paste to your stylesheet. For me is the easiest way to achieve what you need. If you don't have access to Fireworks, you can google for CSS gradient generators, like this [here](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/).

Comment: Try the `border-image property` Maybe this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717127/css3-gradient-borders

Comment: @estebanrincon Yes, and there may be some useful reading here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906983/css-two-color-borders

Comment: Just keep in mind that border-radius is not supported in IE8 and earlier web browsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Straight copied from a project I'm working on. Just change the colors your way. Needs only a little effort ;)

```css
    .btn-primary {
      box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 0 #54a3f7;
      background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #007dc1 5%, #0061a7 100%);
      border-radius: 3px;
      border: 1px solid #124d77;
      display: inline-block;
      cursor: pointer;
      color: #ffffff;
      padding: 6px 24px;
      text-decoration: none;
      text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #154682;
    }

    .btn-primary:hover {
      background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0061a7 5%, #007dc1 100%);
    }

    .btn-primary:active {
      position: relative;
      top: 1px;
    }
```

```html
<a class="btn-primary">Button galore</a>
```

Comment: This is Great! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be done using this CSS code:

```
div {
    -moz-box-shadow:    inset 0 0 2px #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px #fff;
    box-shadow:         inset 0 0 2px #fff;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `border-radius` and `box-shadow` should work.

Here is an example.

```css
body {
  background-color: #111;
}

div {
  border-top-left-radius: 6px;
  border-top-right-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: 0 -2px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  background-color: #444;
  min-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: This is for an outer shadow. I think an inner shadow is needed in the question.

Comment: @MajidSadr - You are probably right. It is kind of hard to see on the cropped image.

Comment: Thank you very much! it helped me a lot.