# How to add colors on the corner of card CSS?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have an example basic bootstrap card like below

Example 1:
[image: Example 1]

I want to draw blue and green color side by side but I only could draw blue like below

Example 2:
[image: Example 2]

When I try to give both classes at the same time it doesnt work.The one is always getting overwritten.

```
 <div class="card blue green">
    <div class="card-body">Basic card</div>
  </div>
```

How to add them side by side?Seems like `:before` doesnt help.

**Expected**
[image: Expected]

Snippet is available below

```css
.green:before{border-left: 5px solid #73BD07;}
.blue:before{border-left: 5px solid #4D33DC;}
.card:before{content: '';position: absolute;top: 0;left: 0;height: 100%;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Card</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body> 
 
<div class="container">
  <h2>Basic Card</h2>
  <div class="card blue green">
    <div class="card-body">Basic card</div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: seems to be working. what is the problem?

Comment: I can't see blue and green color side by side at the same time that's the problem

Comment: `border-left` use to make the border

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Two color borders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906983/two-color-borders)

Comment: Please add expected output image in question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your `green:before` is overwritten by `card:before` since these classes are on the same `div` element. You can avoid this by using `.green:after` instead.

```css
.green:after{
 content: '';
 border-left: 5px solid #73BD07;
 position: absolute;
 left: 5px;
 top: 0;
 height: 100%;
}
.blue:before{border-left: 5px solid #4D33DC;}
.card:before{content: '';position: absolute;top: 0;left: 0;height: 100%;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Card</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body> 
 
<div class="container">
  <h2>Basic Card</h2>
  <div class="card blue green">
    <div class="card-body">Basic card</div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you accept this as answered if it solved your problem, so that your question will be marked as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Add a green border `::before` pseudo elements.

```css
.green{position:relative;}
.green::before{
  border-left: 5px solid #73BD07;
  position:absolute;
  content:'';
  top:0;left:0;bottom:0;
}
.blue{border-left: 5px solid #4D33DC !important;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Card</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body> 
 
<div class="container">
  <h2>Basic Card</h2>
  <div class="card blue green">
    <div class="card-body">Basic card</div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you add screenshot about expected result

Comment: Please check the answer.. try only green border in `::before` and blue the remain same.